# SMB/Debian Network copy issue

Tags: networking, debian, smb, intranet

I'm having an issue with a networked drive ( I don't have root access to ) - I can make an smb:// connection to it, it's a CIFS system and it's used by the intranet to share files ( it's definitely functional as other people are using it ) .. for some reason when I mount it on my Debian using Places -> Connect to Server I can get to it fine, but whenever I attempt to copy a file to my local hard drive it fails and says:

"There was an error copying the file into /home/meder"

"Show more details"

"Invalid argument"

Is there any reason why this could be so? I'm positive that there's nothing wrong with the network server but it's just on my setup that it doesn't seem to work... could it be a permissions thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are able to retrieve files using **smbclient**:

> **smbclient** is a client that can ´talk´ to an SMB/CIFS server. It
>   offers an interface similar to that
>          of the ftp program (see ftp(1)). Operations include things
>   like getting files from the server to
>   the
>          local machine, putting files from the local machine to the server,
>   retrieving directory information
>          from the server and so on.

You can also try **smbget**, a wget-like utility for downloading files over SMB.

**smbstatus** can help you debug Samba connections, but you probably won't be able to run it without sudo permissions.

**Edit:** [Accessing an SMB share with Linux machines](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html): An overview of how to use smbclient.

Comment: I went to the terminal and 'smbclient' was not a command. I went into aptitude and installed it. 

What difference would it make using whatever Debian/gnome's default mounting application as opposed to the smbclient would there be? Is the latter more reliable? Got any links for basic usage of this? 

I'm kind of hesitant, but there's no way I could mess the external network drive up could there, using smbclient? If I don't have sudo permissions? I don't want to start breaking things ( just trying to be cautious ) .

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link that shows you how to use smbclient. No, I don't think this is more reliable, but it should hopefully display a more helpful error if it is unable to copy the file. Just follow the instructions in the link. Also look at the man pages for these tools if you feel hesitant: At the terminal prompt, type `man smbclient`. Look up the man pages for smbget and samba too.